# ANR error when get SensorManager after updating ADT

Tags: android, adt

Today, I updated the ADT plugin in Eclipse to "Android SDK Tools 19" and "Android SDK Platform-tools 11". After that, my application gets ANR error when running on AVD (but is good on a real device). I checked the traces.txt file and find these information:

```
Cmd line: com.mycomp.myapp

DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0
  | sysTid=379 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008
  | schedstat=( 1037525402 663090534 89 )
  at android.hardware.SensorManager.sensors_module_get_next_sensor(Native Method)
  at android.hardware.SensorManager.<init>(SensorManager.java:559)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSensorManager(ContextImpl.java:1123)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:950)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:363)
  at com.mycomp.myapp.clamato.service.ClamatoService.onCreate(ClamatoService.java:91)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2959)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, I checked the code in ClamatoService.java:91, it's like this:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Obviously, I can not get the sensor information on AVD. I re-created the AVD, but it doesn't help.
Anybody can help?

Thanks.

Comment: please show a minimal piece of code that putting it in a tiny project will cause this problem .

Comment: I'm having the same problem with SDK 20.1 and an APIv4 AVD.